# Combining code for multiple sensors in a single program

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, sensors, temperature-sensor

I need to operate 3 different sensors (taken 6 sensors of each type) by Arduino Mega2560 :-

1. DHT11 (temperature-Humidity sensor)
2. MQ5 (gas sensor) and
3. Soil Moisture sensor
   {taken 6 of each type (total=18).}

I have managed to run each one of them separately and I don't know how to manipulate the code so they could work all together. My background in coding is basic, so it would be great help if someone can help me for combining these codes.

Here are the sketches:

**MQ5 Code:**

```
int sensor=7;
int gas_value;
void setup()
{

pinMode(sensor,INPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{

gas_value=digitalRead(sensor);
Serial.println(gas_value);
}
```

{other digital pins to be used: D6,D5,D4,D3,D2}

**DHT11 Code:**

```
#include <dht.h>
#include <dht.h>
#include "dht.h"
#define dht_apin A0 // Analog Pin sensor is connected to
dht DHT;

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);//Delay to let system boot
  Serial.println("DHT11 Humidity & temperature Sensor\n\n");
  delay(1000);//Wait before accessing Sensor

}//end "setup()"

void loop(){
  //Start of Program 

    DHT.read11(dht_apin);

    Serial.print("Current humidity = ");
    Serial.print(DHT.humidity);
    Serial.print("%  ");
    Serial.print("temperature = ");
    Serial.print(DHT.temperature); 
    Serial.println("C  ");

    delay(5000);//Wait 5 seconds before accessing sensor again.

  //Fastest should be once every two seconds.

}// end loop()
```

{analog pins for other sensors: A1,A2,A3,A4,A5}

**Soil_Moisture Sensor Code:**

```
int sensor_pin = A6;
int output_value ;

void setup() {

   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.println("Reading From the Sensor ...");
   delay(2000);

   }

void loop() {

   output_value= analogRead(sensor_pin);
   output_value = map(output_value,550,0,0,100);
   Serial.print("Mositure : ");
   Serial.print(output_value);
   Serial.println("%");
   delay(1000);
   }
```

{Analog pins for other sensors to be used: A6,A7,A8,A9,A10}

Comment: your finished program has to have setup() and loop() blocks ..... what do you feel that should happen with the codes in the three setup() blocks?  ..... what do you think that should happen with the code in the three loop() blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All things before `void setup()` put before one `setup()` function. All things in `void setup()` put to the one `void setup()` - do not duplicate things like `#include` or `Serial.begin()`. And things from `loop()` function put to the `loop()` function.
It's a good practice to don't use `delay()` in  `loop()` when you are processing more things than one. Instead of `delay()` use `millis()` to get current uptime and after that compare this uptime to last uptime of check.

I modified your code, so read it and try it.

```
#include <dht.h>

#define dht_apin A0 // Analog Pin sensor is connected to
dht DHT;


int sensor=7;
int gas_value;

int sensor_pin = A6;
int output_value ;


unsigned long gas_last_time = 0;
unsigned long dht11_last_time = 0;
unsigned long analog_last_time = 0;



void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(sensor,INPUT);
}

void loop(){
  if(millis() - gas_last_time >= 10){
    gas_last_time = millis();

    gas_value=digitalRead(sensor);
    Serial.println(gas_value);
  }


  if(millis() - dht11_last_time >= 5000){
    dht11_last_time = millis();

    DHT.read11(dht_apin);

    Serial.print("Current humidity = ");
    Serial.print(DHT.humidity);
    Serial.print("%  ");
    Serial.print("temperature = ");
    Serial.print(DHT.temperature); 
    Serial.println("C  ");
  }


  if(millis() - analog_last_time >= 1000){
    analog_last_time = millis();

    output_value= analogRead(sensor_pin);
    output_value = map(output_value,550,0,0,100);
    Serial.print("Mositure : ");
    Serial.print(output_value);
    Serial.println("%");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious help, specially in letting me know the basic things you told me via your code. A lot of thanks to you, because of all help by all you guys, I completed my code.(i'm sorry for replying too late from the day of completion of code)

Comment: @Deepanshu No problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

In general:

All `#define`s and `#include`s get put from all separate sketches, at the top.

Globals and function definitions (except for `setup()` and `loop()`) get mixed together below the `#define`s and `#include`s.

All code in the separate `setup()`s get put in the combined `setup()`.

All code in the separate `loop()`s get put in the combined `loop()`.

You have to be aware that any `loop()` from the separate programs that include a `delay()` will likely have to be refactored to use the same kind of scheduled execution method as the [Blink Without Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) example from Arduino. `delay()` stops the whole program while it twiddles thumbs, which means your other sensors aren't being read or managed during that time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious help. Because of all help by all you guys, I completed my code.(i'm sorry for replying too late from the day of completion of code)